# What is this RPG set in a cartoon universe?

Tags: product-identification

I remember I used run a few games using an RPG which was based on a cartoon universe. It was really fun, some of the skills were outrageous. I cannot remember the name at all. Does anyone else know it?

Comment: This needs more details, otherwise it's just a guessing game. Do you remember rules, dice or props used, names of things on rulesheets, parts of sessions/premade adventures, timespan, publisher, anything?

Comment: “Outrageous cartoon universe” is kind of specific, in that I also guessed the accepted answer.

Comment: @okeefe I have to disagree; I thought of Pitfalls & Penguins.

Comment: Or it could have been "Teenagers from outer space"

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You're probably thinking of [TOON: the Cartoon Roleplaying Game](http://www.sjgames.com/toon/), from Steve Jackson Games, published originally in the 80's, though I played it back in the 90's (and still have the rulebook at home somewhere, as well as the Toon ACE Catalog book). It looks like it's still available as a PDF from SJG.

It was a lot of fun, though not really sustainable for anything more than the annual one-off convention game. It did capture the feel of old looney tunes cartoons.

Wikipedia has this to say of the mechanics, which seem to match your memory:

> The game uses a very simple skill-based task resolution system based on a list of only 23 skills that cover all possible character actions. These are assigned to four controlling attributes, humorously named "Muscle" (strength), "Zip" (dexterity and speed), "Smarts" (intelligence) and "Chutzpah" (pushiness and self-confidence).[3] In addition, characters can have optional "Shticks", which give them unusual cartoon-like abilities, such as flying or invisibility.

[image: Cover of TOON rulebook]

Comment: Hey yeah thanks for that! I wish I still had it. I remember it was really easy to pick up and start playing.

Comment: There was also a GURPS sourcebook for Toon, called GURPS: Toon -- it's extremely rare, long out of print, and lets you combine the silliness of Toon with the crunchiness of GURPS (though I've heard/read it had many simplifications of the GURPS rules written in and can serve as a good guide for simplifying GURPS for other milieus).  One interesting feature of the original Toon (not sure if it was reproduced in the GURPS version, but it seems likely) is that nothing can actually KILL a character.  Bomb goes off?  You're coated in soot and your hair stands on end.  Poison?  You turn green.  Etc.

Comment: @ZeissIkon Are you sure about *GURPS Toon*? That is, do you have a link or anything? *Wikipedia* doesn't list such an item, and the only SJG mention I could find (after an admittedly brief search) is from [7/22/97](http://www.sjgames.com/ill/1997/ill-jul97.html). (This is not because I *doubt* you but because *I want that book!*)

Comment: I'm at work, and gaming sites are blocked by network security, but yes, I'm sure about GURPS Toon.  I recall it coming up in a copyright discussion some years ago with a direct and acidic comment from, IIRC, Sean Punch.  I can't verify, but try this:  https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=3&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwi9n6WS2LTPAhWBKCYKHW0iBHAQrAIIMigAMAI&url=http%3A%2F%2Fforums.sjgames.com%2Fshowthread.php%3Ft%3D90214%26page%3D4&usg=AFQjCNGabEmmIAeaO3eNH-EGaiIUpNLw8A&bvm=bv.134052249,d.eWE and http://www.weirdrealm.com/gurps/toonmanga.html

Comment: @ZeissIkon The first link is to a brainstorming thread about homebrewing *GURPS Toon* while the second to a *GURPS Toon* homebrew Web page. I look  forward to an update!

Comment: I'll try to remember to check when I'm on an uncontrolled connection.  Meanwhile, the copyright discussion may actually have been about GURPS *Bunnies and Burrows*.  Been a LONG time -- it was on USENET newsgroups...

Comment: @ZeissIkon Because the question popped up recently as related to another, have you, in the past 2 years or so, been able to visit an uncontrolled connection? I'm still interested in *GURPS Toon.*

Comment: @HeyICanChan I'm at work, and if anything the network is more restricted than it was then; my favorite gun/shooting site will no longer load (though the last time that happened, it was a profile starting to corrupt).  Might try emailing S. John Ross, he can probably at least confirm that it existed.  Or email the official SJGames box.